# How can I send message from Kamailio SIP server (kamailio.cfg) to the SDN controller using HTTP POST?

Tags: http-post, sip, kamailio

I would like to know how can I send certain message from Kamailio SIP server to the SDN controller. It doesn't matter if it is http/xhttp/http_client etc. module.

My idea is:

1. SIP message comes to the Kamailio.
2. Kamailio processes message in kamailio.cfg and recognize that some info must be send to the controller.
3. Kamailio sends a message (defined by me) to the SDN controller using HTTP POST.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http_client module for that.

https://www.kamailio.org/docs/modules/devel/modules/http_client.html

For determine part of messages you can use textops or message-specific info, see kamailio.cfg.sample

https://kamailio.org/docs/modules/5.0.x/modules/textopsx.html